# Point Django at different Python version

Tags: python, django, path

Django application requires a later version of Python. I just installed it to `2.5` (from `2.4`) and now when I do a `python` at the command line, it says `2.5.2`.

Having said that, Django still says `Python Version: 2.4.3`.

How do I correct this? I've rebooted / restarted / redeployed to no avail.

Comment: Django doesn't have control of which Python version is running. The Python version used by the web server will depend on how that web server is deployed. What server are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have it backwards.

Django is added to Python's environment.

When you install a new Python, you must reinstall everything -- including Django -- for the new Python.

Once you have the new Django in the new Python, your `PATH` settings determine which Python you're using.

The version of Python (and the `PYTHONPATH`) determine which Django you'll use.

Comment: Does this mean I install django and everything else in the bin directory of the new python?

Answer (score 5):

How are you running Django? If it's via the development server, you can explicitly choose the version of Python you're using - `python2.5 manage.py runserver`.

However, if you're using `mod_python` or `mod_wsgi` these are fixed to the version of Python that was used when they were compiled. If you need to change this, you'll need to recompile, or find a packaged version for your distribution that uses the updated Python.

Answer (score 0):

django uses /usr/bin/env python IIRC.
So, wherever your path points (which python) is the python that gets used.  dependent upon your system, you can point your path to the python that you want to use.  However, on some OS (CentOS for example) this is a bad idea.