# How do I set Django to use Python 2.7 instead of the default Python 2.4?

Tags: python, django

I am using CentOS. The default python installed is 2.4 and I also installed 2.7 in order to use Django.

How can I configure Django to use `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` instead of just the default `python` command?

I have to leave the default Python as 2.4 because other services such as `yum` don't run with 2.7.

Or is there other solution?

Comment: Don't.  Use python2.7 explicitly.  You'll be much, much happier.

Comment: In a development environment it should be easy to edit the shebang in `manage.py` to use `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` as you wish.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796105/point-django-at-different-python-version

Answer (score 4):

mod_wsgi is linked with specific version of Python. You have to recompile it with Python 2.7 and make Apache load new module (by editing file like `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/wsgi.load` or `/etc/apache2/modules.d/70_mod_wsgi.conf`).

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues

Answer (score 1):

Just run this command into your command shell: `python2.7 /path/to/manage.py runserver`

Then Django will run under python 2.7

Comment: but this is with Apache and WSGI

Comment: This works for me PERFECTLY... but how do I set it up so that I don't have to type the python version every time?

Comment: @xckpd7 If you are working in virtual environment it is very easy.
Type the command: `source /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate` and then you can just run with: `python /path/to/manage.py runserver`

Answer (score 0):

The [answer](http://www.arthurkoziel.com/2008/10/22/working-virtualenv/) [is](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/) [to](http://iamzed.com/2009/05/07/a-primer-on-virtualenv/) [use](http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip/) [`virtualenv`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) [to](http://j2labs.tumblr.com/post/2904859594/python-2-6-2-7-and-3-1-with-virtualenv) [set](http://jontourage.com/2011/02/09/virtualenv-pip-basics/) [up](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Using+a+Virtualenv+Sandbox) [a](http://www.mahdiyusuf.com/post/5282169518/beginners-guide-easy-install-pip-and-virtualenv-1) [virtual](http://mitchfournier.com/2010/06/25/getting-started-with-virtualenv-isolated-python-environments/) [environment](http://simononsoftware.com/virtualenv-tutorial/) [for](http://blog.praveengollakota.com/47430655) [python2.7](http://www.gyford.com/phil/writing/2011/06/27/virtualenv-webfaction.php) and to [install](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-virtualenv-pip-and-django-site-gen-to-quickly-start-new-django-projects/) [your](http://www.slideshare.net/jnials/virtualenv-9208950) [stuff](http://blog.sidmitra.com/manage-multiple-projects-better-with-virtuale) into [that](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/4253/simple-virtualenv-usage-with-django) [sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/virtualenv).

Here is some code to get you going:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
$ sudo easy_install -U pip
$ sudo pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
$ mkdir ~/.virtualenvs
$ sudo cat >> ~/.bashrc << EOF
# virtualenvwrapper setup
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV_ARGS='--no-site-packages --python=python2.7'
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
EOF
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ mkvirtualenv test
$ pip install django
```

I am assuming that CentOS uses `sudo` like Ubuntu does. Substitute the native call if not.