# Incorrect python path django on traceback

Tags: python, django, mod-wsgi, python-3.4

I am running python3.4 and django 1.7.5 on a ubuntu server with apache2 and mod wsgi and virtualenv. I am running into an issue that I believe is caused by django using the wrong python path. In this view I was only trying to print out the python version because I had suspected it to have been wrong.

**Fair warning:** I am new to python, django, ubuntu and apache. But I have experience in other sysadmin and programming. So this question may be extremely obvious to someone that has been using this stack for awhile. If so, my apologies.

**Here is the traceback**

```
Environment:

Django Version: 1.7.5
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'helloworld')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/var/www/unchained/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/unchained/helloworld/views.py" in helloworld
7.     html = dict("<html><body><b>", "Django: ", django.get_version(), "<br>Python: ", sys.version)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 5
```

And the main error:

```
TypeError at /

dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 5

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://10.1.1.75/
Django Version:     1.7.5
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 5

Exception Location:     /var/www/unchained/helloworld/views.py in helloworld, line 7
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.8
Python Path:    

['/var/www/unchained',
'/var/www/unchained/bin/python',
'/var/www/unchained/lib/python3.4/site-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-pack
```

**However,** when I do

```
source bin/activate
python manage.py shell
>>>import sys
>>>print(sys.version)
```

I get `3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) [GCC 4.8.2]`. That makes me think that django is using the correct virtualenv with the correct python. However, why would the traceback show python 2.7.8??

I realize I am using dict incorrectly, I was intentionally trying to throw an error to get a traceback.

Here is my apache virtualhost minus my personal info

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/static/robots.txt
    Alias /favicon.ico /var/www/static/favicon.ico
    Alias /static/ /var/www/unchained/Unchained/static/
    <Directory /var/www/unchained/Unchained/static>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    WSGIDaemonProcess example.com processes=2 threads=2 display-name=%{GROUP}
    WSGIProcessGroup example.com

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/unchained/Unchained/wsgi.py

    <Directory /var/www/unchained/Unchained>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Allow from all
            </Files>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Is this apache2 setup correctly importing the wsgi and the virtual paths to the python?

I realize this post got very lengthy, and I apologize, but there is a bunch to put in here!!

Thanks

Comment: this thread may shed some light... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1796105/point-django-at-different-python-version. Also, check the settings of your web server in `mod wsgi` for a python version.

Comment: As per this link https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationDirectives#WSGIDaemonProcess , did you try passing python-path as the argument to WSGIDaemonProcess statement ?

Comment: @vijayalakshmid I did. What I am going to try now is WSGIPythonHome in the wsgi.config and see if that works. To do so I will have to recompile though.

Comment: Recompiling did not work either. I tried multiple ways. So i took the easy way out, started over on fresh ubuntu and went with uwsgi and nginx instead. Had it running in about 30 minutes. Easy peasy